# Does the standard define list initialization with superfluous braces (e.g. T{{{10}}})?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, initializer-list

When using a braced-init-list containing multiple braced-init-list, what are the rules defined by the standard for B, C, and D?

For B, I believe this scenario is defined within the standard as a braced-init-list with a single element and therefore it calls `Test(int)` directly with no temporary - but I am unable to find where.

For C and D, I am unsure of whether this is undefined behavior or not.

I am also interested in what occurs when using more than a single element i.e. `{{{1, 2}}}` and if this changes the behavior for B, C, or D?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
    Test(const int a) {
        // A and B call this
    }

    Test(Test&& test) = delete;
    Test(const Test& test) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    Test a{1}; // calls Test(int)
    Test b{{2}}; // B
    Test c{{{3}}}; // C
    Test d{{{{4}}}}; // D
    // Test e{a}; error, deleted copy constructor
    // Test f{Test{0}}; error, deleted move constructor
    return 0;
}
```

GCC `g++ my_prog.cpp` gives me an error for C and D only:

```
my_prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
my_prog.cpp:16:17: error: too many braces around initializer for 'int' [-fpermissive]
     Test c{{{3}}};
                 ^
my_prog.cpp:4:14: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'Test::Test(int)'
     Test(int a) {
          ~~~~^
```

Comment: Be warned that the treatment of redundant braces has been the subject of multiple core language issues, so expect divergence between implementations, between them and the standard, and between standard versions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you have

```
Test b{{2}};
```

[[dcl.init.list]/3.7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#3.7) states.

> Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match], [over.match.list]). [...]

and looking in [over.match] we have [[over.match.ctor]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match#ctor-1)

> When objects of class type are direct-initialized, copy-initialized from an expression of the same or a derived class type ([dcl.init]), or default-initialized, overload resolution selects the constructor. For direct-initialization or default-initialization that is not in the context of copy-initialization, the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized. For copy-initialization (including default initialization in the context of copy-initialization), the candidate functions are all the converting constructors ([class.conv.ctor]) of that class. The argument list is the expression-list or assignment-expression of the initializer.

So we consider the constructors, find

```
Test(const int a)
```

and then we use the element `{2}` as initializer for `a` which  uses [[dcl.init.list]/3.9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#3.9)

> Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type E and either T is not a reference type or its referenced type is reference-related to E, the object or reference is initialized from that element (by copy-initialization for copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for direct-list-initialization); if a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert the element to T, the program is ill-formed.

With

```
Test c{{{3}}};
// and
Test d{{{{4}}}};
```

we do the same thing.  We look at the constructors and find

```
Test(const int a)
```

as the only viable one.  When we do and try to initialize `a`, we look to [[dcl.init.list]/3.9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#3.9) again but it doesn't apply here. `{{3}}` and `{{{4}}}` aren't initializer lists with a single type `E`.  A *braced-init-list* doesn't have a type so we have to keep going list in [[dcl.init.list]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#3).  When we do we don't meet anything else that matches until [[dcl.init.list]/3.12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#3.12)

> Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.